# Scene Kit contact catagoryBitMasks always returning 1

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

So I'm using a simple collision struct, which I then use to set the catagoryMasks for my collision objects (see below).
However, the didBeginContact function - which is triggered for the correct collisions - says that the colliding node categoryBitMasks are 1, regardless of which node is colliding. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Here's the struct, very similar to Apple's DemoBots example:

```
struct ColliderStruct {
let rawValue: UInt32

var categoryMask: UInt32 {
    return rawValue
}

static var Player: ColliderStruct  { return self.init(rawValue: 1 << 0) }
static var AI: ColliderStruct { return self.init(rawValue: 1 << 1) }
static var Ball: ColliderStruct   { return self.init(rawValue: 1 << 2) }
static var RedGoal: ColliderStruct   { return self.init(rawValue: 1 << 3) }
static var BlueGoal: ColliderStruct   { return self.init(rawValue: 1 << 4) }
static var Arena: ColliderStruct   { return self.init(rawValue: 1 << 5) }

var hashValue: Int {
    return Int(rawValue)
}
```

}

I set the categories like so:

```
arenaGeometry.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderStruct.Arena.hashValue
```

And I check them like this:

```
func physicsWorld(world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBeginContact contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
    //printing to test
    print("A bitmask: \(contact.nodeA.categoryBitMask), B bitmask: \(contact.nodeB.categoryBitMask)")

    if (contact.nodeA.categoryBitMask == ColliderStruct.Player.hashValue || contact.nodeB.categoryBitMask ==  ColliderStruct.Player.hashValue ) {
        print("player hit something!")
    }
}
```

}

However, the bit mask is always reported as being 1 and the the collision never gets through to the second print statement:

```
A bitmask: 1, B bitmask: 1
```

I've been staring at this too long, anything obviously wrong?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you just need to step back from the computer a bit.

```
print("A bitmask: \(contact.nodeA.categoryBitMask), B bitmask: \(contact.nodeB.categoryBitMask)")
```

Should be

```
print("A bitmask: \(contact.nodeA.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask), B bitmask: \(contact.nodeB.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask)")
```

Comment: Oh my word, that's embarrassing. Thank you, and no more late night programming for me.

Comment: We've all done this at some point. What seems nigh impossible at 2am takes five minutes to fix the morning after... a lesson I seem keen to relearn frequently.

Comment: Just did the same thing! Thanks!